# Why this is not true : ${i}^{n}=0$ for every even positive integer $n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, education

Let $i$ be a unit imaginary part , we have  for $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$: $\left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \right)^n = (0+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} ))^n=i\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})=0$     (Using Moiver formual) , I asked why this is work however ${i}^{n}$ gives only $1$ or $-1$ ?

**Edite01** : I edited the question because i meant why I can't let $\cos\theta =0$ before using Moiiver formula

**Edite02**:I edited the question to give some explanations for the recent

**Note** : I think I have a bad uses  for the Moiiver formula !!

Thank you for any help

Comment: Why $(\sin (\pi / 2) )^n = \sin (n \pi / 2)$ ?

Comment: Moiiver formula

Comment: That not what  de Moivre tells us.  $1=\left( sin \frac {\pi}2 \right)^2\neq sin \frac {2\pi}2=sin\, \pi=0$, for example.

Comment: no , i don't mean that : I meant :(isin(pi/2))^n= isin(n(pi/2))

Comment: Yes, $\cos\frac\pi2=0$, but no,  $\cos\frac{n\pi}2\ne 0$ in general

Comment: pleas try to undersand my problem (substition by theta before applying Moiiver formula) :we have :$$ \left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \right)^n = \cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta.$$ If $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$  then $$ \left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \right)^n = (0+i\sin(\frac{\pi}{2} ))^n=i\sin(n\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$ for an even integer

Answer (score 3):

It is DeMoivre's rule and you stated it wrong. $$ \left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \right)^n = \cos n \theta + i \sin n \theta.$$ If $n\theta$ is a multiple of $\pi$ the end result is $\pm 1$, not $0$.

Comment: No. if you let $\theta = \frac \pi 2$ then $(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^n = \cos \frac{n\pi}{2} + i \sin \frac{n\pi}{2}$.

Comment: nice , if i let $ \theta =\frac{\pi}{2} $   then   $\left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta \right)^n =isin\frac {n\pi}{2}$ , the problem if i let $ \theta =\frac{\pi}{2} $ before using Moiiver Formual this what i meant